# Hiw to merge sets of elements in an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array filled with U.S. state names from scraping a website.

The problem is that all of the states that have two words  ended up as seperate elements in the array. "New York" is in the array as `["New", "York"]`.

I need to solve this for every two-word state in the array.

```
 ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado",
 "Connecticut", "Florida", "Georgia", "Idaho", "Illinois" "Indiana",
 "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", 
 "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri",
 "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New", "Hampshire", "New", "Jersey",
 "New", "Mexico", "New", "York", "North", "Carolina", "North", "Dakota", 
 "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "South", "Carolina",
 "South", "Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", 
 "Washington", "West", "Virginia", "Wisconsin","Wyoming"]
```

```
def scrape_koa_states
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://koa.com/campgrounds/"))
  title = doc.search("h4").text
  title_array = title.split
  title_array = title_array.delete_if{|ele| ele == "in"}
  title_array.map {|ele| ele.gsub!("Campgrounds", "")}
  new_array = title_array[2, 56]
  binding.pry
end
```

```
title = doc.search("h4").text
=> "KOA NewsletterCampgrounds in AlabamaCampgrounds in AlaskaCampgrounds in ArizonaCampgrounds in ArkansasCampgrounds in CaliforniaCampgrounds in ColoradoCampgrounds in ConnecticutCampgrounds in FloridaCampgrounds in GeorgiaCampgrounds in IdahoCampgrounds in IllinoisCampgrounds in IndianaCampgrounds in IowaCampgrounds in KansasCampgrounds in KentuckyCampgrounds in LouisianaCampgrounds in MaineCampgrounds in MarylandCampgrounds in MassachusettsCampgrounds in MichiganCampgrounds in MinnesotaCampgrounds in MississippiCampgrounds in MissouriCampgrounds in MontanaCampgrounds in NebraskaCampgrounds in NevadaCampgrounds in New HampshireCampgrounds in New JerseyCampgrounds in New MexicoCampgrounds in New YorkCampgrounds in North CarolinaCampgrounds in North DakotaCampgrounds in OhioCampgrounds in OklahomaCampgrounds in OregonCampgrounds in PennsylvaniaCampgrounds in South CarolinaCampgrounds in South DakotaCampgrounds in TennesseeCampgrounds in TexasCampgrounds in UtahCampgrounds in VermontCampgrounds in VirginiaCampgrounds in WashingtonCampgrounds in West VirginiaCampgrounds in WisconsinCampgrounds in WyomingCampgrounds in AlbertaCampgrounds in British ColumbiaCampgrounds in ManitobaCampgrounds in New BrunswickCampgrounds in Newfoundland and LabradorCampgrounds in Nova ScotiaCampgrounds in OntarioCampgrounds in Prince Edward IslandCampgrounds in Quebec"
```

Comment: Can you share what's the data or code you have and what'd be the expected output from that?

Comment: sure I just added what the current output is so you get a better sense of the full output. Posting the code in there in a second

Comment: It seems it's better you modify the current scraper code to get the whole state name. Otherwise you'd have to know beforehand what are the states that need to be "joined".

Comment: Ok the code is there. So I achieved the goal of getting all of the states into the array, however all the two word states got separated. What I would like to try to do now is iterate over the array and pout the two word states back together as one element basically

Comment: I just posted a snippet of how the data comes in from the scraped document

Comment: Yeah, I think I just got one other idea I am going to try out and hopefully that will work.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968). You want to merge elements but you're extracting the data wrong, which _should_ be the question you ask about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can just get each `a h4` elements, map their text getting the string value between `Camgrounds in` and the end of the string.

You can try with something like this:

```
states = doc.search('a h4').map do |state|
  state.text[/(?<=Campgrounds in )(.*)$/]
end
p states
# ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Florida", "Georgia", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming", "Alberta", "British Columbia", "Manitoba", "New Brunswick", "Newfoundland and Labrador", "Nova Scotia", "Ontario", "Prince Edward Island", "Quebec"]
```

With `doc.search("h4")` you're getting every `h4` element from the document. You can filter it out before if you know that the content you need is always inside an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with the code.

`search` returns a [NodeSet](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html):

```rb
doc.search('h4').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
```

A NodeSet is a collection, like an array, and `text`, when extracting the NodeSet's Node's text concatenates the results together into a String.

```rb
doc.search('h4').text[0..40] # => "KOA NewsletterCampgrounds in AlabamaCampg"
```

Recovering from that is a nightmare and we see people ask about it often because they didn't read the documentation.

This is from NodeSet's [`text` documentation](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#inner_text-instance_method):

> Get the inner text of all contained Node objects
>
> Note: This joins the text of all Node objects in the NodeSet:
>
> ```
> doc = Nokogiri::XML('<xml><a><d>foo</d><d>bar</d></a></xml>')
> doc.css('d').text # => "foobar"
> ```
>
> Instead, if you want to return the text of all nodes in the NodeSet:
>
> ```
> doc.css('d').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
> ```

So, as the example shows, use:

```rb
doc.search('h4').map(&:text)[0..4] # => ["KOA Newsletter", "Campgrounds in Alabama", "Campgrounds in Alaska", "Campgrounds in Arizona", "Campgrounds in Arkansas"]
```

*Note that I'm using a slice of `[0..4]` now to reduce the output of the array. You don't want to do that. Unless you want to.*

Next, CSS and XPath have ways of nosing around inside nodes to see what their child nodes are, so let them. CSS almost always is more readable so I use it most of the time:

```rb
doc.search('h4:contains("Campgrounds")').map(&:text)[0..4] # => ["Campgrounds in Alabama", "Campgrounds in Alaska", "Campgrounds in Arizona", "Campgrounds in Arkansas", "Campgrounds in California"]
```

Now it's trivial to clean up the results:

```rb
doc.search('h4:contains("Campgrounds")').map { |h4| 
  h4.text[15..-1]
}
```

Which results in:

```
# => ["Alabama",
#     "Alaska",
#     "Arizona",
#     "Arkansas",
#     "California",
#     "Colorado",
#     "Connecticut",
#     "Florida",
#     "Georgia",
#     "Idaho",
#     "Illinois",
#     "Indiana",
#     "Iowa",
#     "Kansas",
#     "Kentucky",
#     "Louisiana",
#     "Maine",
#     "Maryland",
#     "Massachusetts",
#     "Michigan",
#     "Minnesota",
#     "Mississippi",
#     "Missouri",
#     "Montana",
#     "Nebraska",
#     "Nevada",
#     "New Hampshire",
#     "New Jersey",
#     "New Mexico",
#     "New York",
#     "North Carolina",
#     "North Dakota",
#     "Ohio",
#     "Oklahoma",
#     "Oregon",
#     "Pennsylvania",
#     "South Carolina",
#     "South Dakota",
#     "Tennessee",
#     "Texas",
#     "Utah",
#     "Vermont",
#     "Virginia",
#     "Washington",
#     "West Virginia",
#     "Wisconsin",
#     "Wyoming",
#     "Alberta",
#     "British Columbia",
#     "Manitoba",
#     "New Brunswick",
#     "Newfoundland and Labrador",
#     "Nova Scotia",
#     "Ontario",
#     "Prince Edward Island",
#     "Quebec"]
```

Comment: Hello Tin Man, yeah as soon as I posted for help about this took a look at the returned data and did something similar to what Sebastian said above, but what you provided is extremely handy knowledge to have! Thanks for not bashing my newbie attempt at this. I 'm trying, lol!!!!

Comment: Don't apologize for being new at coding. We've all been there. Just do your due diligence, write good questions following "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and you'll do fine.

Comment: Right on, yeah after seeing the responses and solutions to my issue I can clearly see that I was asking the wrong question. I was trying to ask about fixing the output I got when I should've been asking about getting better or proper output from my search. Again, thanks a bunch!!! Much appreciated.